# unable to retrieve json response from inner function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using a $.getJSON method to retrieve weather data from open weather.  When i use an explicit URL string for the document ready function, I am able to retrieve the values from the response JSON and write them to the page.
This works fine.

I am attempting to create a basic user input to query the data by zip code.  I've created a nested function with the API URL as a concatenated string.  I am unable to determine why the code in the nested function submitZip is not writing the response to the page in the same way that the document ready function did.

I have tried debugging and it appears that the string is concatenating correctly and making the API call successfully, but for some reason I am unable retrieve data from the response.  Any ideas on I may have incorrect here?

```js
var place = document.getElementById("meat");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=36830&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial", function (data) {
        place.innerText = data.main.temp;
    });
}); 
var weather = document.getElementById("Weather");
function submitZip() {
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("Zip-Code");
    var fullURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode.value + "&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial";
    
    $.getJSON(fullURL, function (data) {
        //var currentTemp = api.main.temp;
        weather.innertText = data.main.temp;
        
    });
    return weather;
};


var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-zip");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitZip, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="header">This page will be utilitzed as practice for API</h2>
    <p id="meat"></p>
        <form>
      <p>Enter the Zip Code to see the Weather there!</p>
      <input id = "Zip-Code" type="text"/>
      <input id = "submit-zip" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div>
      <p id= "Weather"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your page gets reloaded as soon as you press the submit button.
Change the type of the button to `button` or 
prevent the default behaviour using `event.prevenDefault()`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="header">This page will be utilitzed as practice for API</h2>
    <p id="meat"></p>
        <form>
      <p>Enter the Zip Code to see the Weather there!</p>
      <input id = "Zip-Code" type="text"/>
      <input id = "submit-zip" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div>
      <p id= "Weather"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var place = document.getElementById("meat");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=36830&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial", function (data) {
        place.innerText = data.main.temp;
    });
}); 
var weather = document.getElementById("Weather");
function submitZip(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var zipCode = document.getElementById("Zip-Code");
    var fullURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode.value + "&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial";

    $.getJSON(fullURL, function (data) {
        //var currentTemp = api.main.temp;
        weather.innertText = data.main.temp;

    });
    return weather;
};


var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-zip");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitZip, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Two issues:

- The form is submitted (and reloads) when you click the button. Avoid this by calling `e.preventDefault()` on the event object.
- You have a spelling mistake in `weather.innertText`. Remove the extra `t` in the middle

Working code:

```js
var place = document.getElementById("meat");
var header = document.getElementById("header");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=36830&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial", function (data) {
        place.innerText = data.main.temp;
    });
}); 
var weather = document.getElementById("Weather");
function submitZip(e) {
    var zipCode = document.getElementById("Zip-Code");
    var fullURL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=" + zipCode.value + "&APPID=75ed54453a6e806917cfa439b3fb1dd9&units=imperial";
    
    $.getJSON(fullURL, function (data) {
        //var currentTemp = api.main.temp;
        weather.innerText = data.main.temp;
        
    });
    e.preventDefault();
};


var submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-zip");
submitButton.addEventListener('click', submitZip, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
    <title>Weather</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2 id="header">This page will be utilitzed as practice for API</h2>
    <p id="meat"></p>
        <form>
      <p>Enter the Zip Code to see the Weather there!</p>
      <input id = "Zip-Code" type="text"/>
      <input id = "submit-zip" type="submit"/>
    </form>
    <div>
      <p id= "Weather"></p>
    </div>
  </body>
  </html>
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you.  not sure how the typo of the innerText got there, but clearly the lack of the e.preventDefault(); syntax was the source of my troubles.